# Calling format function within format function in R

Tags: r

I was trying this piece of code in R about data-time formats in one of the online courses. It gives me the required output but I am unable to figure out how it works, especially the referencing a function name with the same function.

```
str2 <- "2012-3-12 14:23:08"

# Convert the strings to POSIXct objects:  time2

time2 = as.POSIXct(str2, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Convert times to formatted strings: Confusion over this piece of code format within format

format(time2, format="%H hours: %M minutes %p")
```

The output is **"14 hours: 23 minutes PM"**, which is fine. But, I am unable to figure out the syntax of how *format* within *format* works. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `?strptime` will give you different ways you can format time.

Comment: @d.b: I check the documentation of format using ?format. It does not take any arguments by the name of *format*.

Comment: Maybe check ?format.POSIXct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` is a [generic function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/UseMethod). The  correct method will be called based on the class of the object passed as the first argent. For `POSIXct` objects the method `format.POSIXct`   will be called.
`?format.POSIXct` shows it accepts the `format` argument.

Comment: After reading about generic functions, this has been my understanding:  the main reason why generic functions are introduced is to so that the person who is programming need not remember so many function names. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Kasa That is not the main reason. Generics is just a style of [Object-Oriented Programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) and one of the ways that R implements OOP.